# I have a cell that has a formula that references a named range, but the cell is inside the name range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is giving me a circular reference. How do I exclude the cell from the name range without having to create a whole new named range?

```
=IF(Q4="3s", "red", 
IF(Q4="3", 
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("red", _SB1)), "red/blk", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("red/blk",_SB1)), "red/wht",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("red/wht", _SB1)), "red/grn", 
"red"))), ""))
```

This is the equation. What I am trying to do is have it look at Q4 and if it has 3 I want it to return red, if there is already a red in the named range, I want it to return red/blk, then if there is red/blk it returns red/wht, and if there is red/wht return red/grn. But the cell with this formula is in the named range. I want it to look at

Comment: @BigBen Does the edit help explain more of what I am trying to do?

Comment: Try creating a helper column that replicates the named range but excludes the cell in question. This way, your formula in cell B6 can reference this helper column instead of the original named range.

Comment: If you have a value in a cell and you want to change that value in the cell, then you need to use vba and not a formula.

Comment: In context to this new post, the last post of OP which is deleted those who can view might help what they are trying to achieve **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77367959/i-am-trying-to-have-the-name-range-in-this-formula-be-the-name-of-the-cell-to-th)**. Also OP was using `Excel 97-2003` and presently may be the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

I used LET to replicate the named range on Excel for mobile, but the idea is the same:
You wrap your named range in FILTER (or AGGREGATE) and exclude the current row from the calculation:

```
=LET(_SB1,S1:S5,
IF(Q4="3s", "red", IF(Q4="3", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("red", FILTER(_SB1,ROW(_SB1)<>ROW()))), "red/blk", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("red/blk",FILTER(_SB1,ROW(_SB1)<>ROW()))), "red/wht", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("red/wht", FILTER(_SB1,ROW(_SB1)<>ROW()))), "red/grn", "red"))), ""))
     )
```